# How to add new language field in attributes magento

Tags: php, magento

I installed Spanish pack manually, by uploading to the locale folder. it works, but Spanish does not appear in manage attributes -> edit attribute -> labels/options,  there is just English,French and German. How to add new language field and/or which config file or setting control these?

I searched a lot on Google and on SOF. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Spanish Store View. Configuration -> Manage Shops.

Add a store in and you will get the label options in the attributes.